# Getting 504 Gateway Timeout on Superset with Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-superset

I am using superset as my data visualization tool. But I am getting 504 Gateway timeout while I am trying to run a long-running query.

My original query took 40 seconds to run in Bigquery console but after 50 sec I am getting 504 error.

I have changed SUPERSET_WEBSERVER_TIMEOUT = 300 in superset_config.py also run with `superset runserver -t 300`

[image]

Comment: Hey, Sirajus, would you mind share how to connect to BigQuery? I am having trouble of passing in the credentials when trying to add a bigquery source

Answer (score 0):

From the Superset documentation[1]:

"If you are seeing timeouts (504 Gateway Time-out) when loading dashboard or explore slice, you are probably behind gateway or proxy server (such as Nginx). If it did not receive a timely response from Superset server (which is processing long queries), these web servers will send 504 status code to clients directly."

Adjusting the timeout on Superset won't help you in this case, since it has no control over the early response from your intermediate proxy. See if you can bypass the proxy or adjust the timeout.

[1] https://superset.incubator.apache.org/faq.html#why-are-my-queries-timing-out

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here is what to do :

Add this between http{} in etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
uwsgi_read_timeout 600s;
proxy_connect_timeout 600;
proxy_send_timeout 600s;
proxy_read_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
```

If you are using gunicorn be sure to launch your app with a larger timeout (mine was 60 seconds so I put 600 secondes